# Explict Converversion of Smart Pointer to raw pointer of pointee type.

Tags: c++

Sorry, if it a very basic question, i am trying to run the following program, and i am getting the segmentation fault.

**What i understand?**

There is a function proc(t)  in which t is conerted to T* by means of operator T *.  Hence while executing the proc(t) function, we will have a pointer type to T*, and which is legal to invoke display () function.

What I want ?

1) Where am i committing the mistake?.

2) Is my understanding is correct?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class sPtr
{
    private:
       T * __pointee;
     public:

        operator T * () {
                cout <<"Inside T* () "<<endl;
        };
    explicit sPtr ( T * t )
    {

      __pointee = t;
    };
    T * operator->() {
        return __pointee;
     }
};

class JTest
{
 private:
        int x;
 public:
   JTest ( int l=100) { x=l; };
    void display ();
};

void JTest::display()
{
  cout <<"Display API x is "<<x<<endl;
}

void proc (JTest * tmp)
{
  cout <<" proc"<<endl;
  tmp->display ();
  cout <<"Invoking JTest -> display "<<endl;
}


int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{
 sPtr <JTest> t(new JTest);
 t->display();
 proc(t);   // Invokes operator T*().

}
```

Comment: Don't use identifiers with two consecutive underscores in them, they are reserved for your compiler and standard library.

Comment: Your `operator T*` doesn't return anything. The code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: that's (maybe) a warning, not an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator T*()` is missing a return statement, so it apparently returns a garbage value (a pointer to a random place in memory), and dereferencing this pointer than segfaults.

How come your compiler didn't error out on this is beyond me.

Comment: This wasn't a required diagnostic. I believe it was (at least partially) introduced in C++11, so conformant compilers should not compile this in c++11 mode

Comment: @sehe You're right, my bad. However, I still can't understand why a compiler (other than Hell++) would have default settings different from "that's an error."

Comment: @angew, my bad. forgot to return ;). Thanks.

Comment: @Whoami If there is a way to make your compiler treat  "non-`void` function missing `return` statement" as an error, I wholeheartedly suggest you use it.

Comment: @Angew I think it was just hard to diagnose in the general case. This is more something for static analysis tools (lint-like). And pushing the burden onto compiler vendors would be slowing standard adoption down. Standards serve the language users, but their heaviness predicts how well vendors will support it.